# Simple raw buffer queue implementation

Tags: c++, performance, queue

I am trying to implement a simple raw queue in C++. This is what I have come up with

```
#include <queue>
#include <cstdint>
#include <array>
#include <cstring>

class simple_queue
{
private:
    static constexpr uint32_t max_msg_size = 4096;
    using char_msg = std::array<char, max_msg_size>;
    std::queue<char_msg> char_queue;

public:
    simple_queue() = default;
    ~simple_queue() = default;
    simple_queue(simple_queue&&) = default;
    simple_queue& operator=(simple_queue&&) = default;

    uint32_t write(const char* const buff, const uint32_t size) noexcept
    {
        const uint32_t size_to_copy = std::min(max_msg_size, size);
        char_msg tmp_msg;
        std::memcpy(&tmp_msg, buff, size_to_copy);
        char_queue.push(std::move(tmp_msg));
        return size_to_copy;
    }

    uint32_t read(char* const buff, const uint32_t size) noexcept
    {
        if (char_queue.empty())
        {
            return 0;
        }
        const uint32_t size_to_copy = std::min(max_msg_size, size);
        std::memcpy(buff, &char_queue.front(), size_to_copy);
        char_queue.pop();
        return size_to_copy;
    }
};
```

Note that I am trying to implement this queue just to store raw char buffers. As far as I understand making it a template does not make sense in this case.

I have played with it a bit and it seems to work as I expect.

- What can I change with this implementation?
- Does it make sense to use a custom allocator in here? I am allocating memory every time I write to the queue; how can I use a custom allocator to allocate some default chunk of memory when the queue is constructed?

Answer (score 2):

You are *not* allocating per se when when writing to the queue. `std::array` is backed by a plain `C`-array on the stack, that gets moved.

So you only ever allocate depending on the underlying container the `std::queue` is based on. By default this is a `std::deque`.

I do not really understand the need for the `std::array` in the type though. Why not just use a `std::string` and limit the size of it to 4096? There is even a constructor that does explicitely that `string (const char* s, size_t n)`

Before I get to the Code there are some other things I would like to mention:

1. why are you not useing std::copy instead of memcpy. The former works better with C++ and will in the end almost always end up as memcpy?
2. You do not need to define the special member functions. In fact you have forgotten 2 of then, aka copy assignment and copy constructor. Why do I say forgotten? Because there is no way to tell. So If you want your queue to be move only then you should actually `delete` those special member functions you dont want.
3. In your read function you never check whether the size you want to read is actually valid. Is that intendend? If so why? A `std::array` is not initialized so the memory in it that is not written by you will be random. You are not writing to it but you are copying it around. So you should actually take the minimum out of `size` and `queue.front().size()`
4. `std::string` has a member function `std::string::copy` that copyies a certain amount of chars to a buffer (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/copy/). I would suggest to use that for writing back to the buffer

That leads me to the following:

```
#include <string>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>

class simple_queue
{
private:
    static constexpr uint32_t max_msg_size = 4096;
    std::queue<std::string, std::vector<std::string>> char_queue;

public:  
   simple_queue(const simple_queue&) = delete;
   simple_queue& operator=(const simple_queue&) = delete;

    uint32_t write(const char* const buff, const uint32_t size) noexcept
    {
        const uint32_t size_to_copy = std::min(max_msg_size, size);
        char_queue.emplace(buff, size_to_copy);
        return size_to_copy;
    }

    uint32_t read(char* const buff, const uint32_t size) noexcept
    {
        if (char_queue.empty())
        {
            return 0;
        }
        std::string& msg = char_queue.front();
        const uint32_t size_to_copy = std::min(msg, size);
        msg.copy(buff, size_to_copy, 0);

        char_queue.pop();
        return size_to_copy;
    }
};
```

EDIT:

I forgot to mention, that now you should use a `std::vector` as backing of the queue as your are not storing a gargantuan array but rather a mall `std::string`.

Note that it actually ends up being the same. The `std::deque` based `std::array` implementation is backed by a linked list, so each array ends up in a node of a linked list, which is kind of similar to the separate allocation of the `std::string`

Comment: You should not use "EDIT tags"; they are only confusing and distracting for people who come to the question or answer for the first time. Edits happen all the time, and anyone interested can just click to see the whole post history.

Comment: Thanks, all of your points are valid. I have updated the implementation and after running benchmarks it is performing much better. However there is still something I would like to improve. With every `.emplace(buff, size_to_copy)` the allocator for `std::string` is called, I would like to get rid of allocation and have it use a pre allocated chunk of memory. I was under the impression it might be easier to do so with `std::array` and that's why I opted to use that instead of `std::string`.

Comment: @miscco
BTW, I did not get why you've mentioned to use `std::vector`, you mean I should use a vector of `char`s?

Comment: @Ali `std::queue` is a container-adaptor. The second template argument it takes is the underlying container. Consequently, in the example i replaced the default container `std::deque` with `std::vector`

Comment: @Ali Regarding your first comment, you will most likely never get rid of all allocations, as the std array is allocated into a container node anyway. In fact it even better to allocate a potentially smaller string than always putting a gargantuan array into `std::deque` node

Comment: @miscco, I see. Very interesting. Using the `std::vector` as the underlying container is actually faster compared to the default(`std::dequeu`?). Why is that?
I do not control the size of the strings and almost all of them are 4KB, the perfect solution to me would be to have some custom allocator so that all `std::string`s can use that pre-allocated space

Comment: @miscco I have been only benchmarking the `write` method. After trying to benchmark `read()` it appears I cannot use `std::vector` as it does not provide `pop_front()` as described [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue). But `std::list` seems to be working really good. I am still wondering why changing the the underlying container can have such a big impact on performance.

Comment: @Ali Std::vector in to always faster. It depends on the use case. Chandler Carruth hat an amathing talk about that topic (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fHNmRkzxHWs). For example std::deque is a container that has to fulfill various requirements. A std::list does not. If you only need those properties a list fulfills, then the list is a better container as it is simpler. Finally, you do not save allocations of the string with the std::array, because that array is allocated into a node of the queue. You cannot avoid that.